# How to launch this DtKsh application?

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I'm working with `Desktop Korn Shell`

You can create examples like this one; So I want to create it

[image: example]

and here's the code of this:

```
#!/usr/dt/bin/dtksh                                            ##directory to invoke
XtInitialize TOPLEVEL dttest1 Dtksh $0
XtSetValues $TOPLEVEL title:"dttest1"
XtCreateManagedWidget BBOARD bboard XmBulletinBoard $TOPLEVEL \
   resizePolicy:RESIZE_NONE height:150 width:250\
   background:SkyBlue
XtCreateManagedWidget BUTTON pushbutton XmPushButton $BBOARD \
   background:goldenrod \
   foreground:MidnightBlue \
   labelString:"Push Here" \
   height:30 width:100 x:75 y:60 shadowThickness:3
XtRealizeWidget $TOPLEVEL
XtMainLoop
```

I've already installed `KSH93` in my linux, and launching this in the terminal I see the error:
[image]

Searching in my `/usr` path there are no of `dt` or `bin` neither `dtksh`

So I've been searching how to create these directories, or install packages to got the but wasn't sucessful or I have no idea how to generate them.

and reading the first chapters of this [Oracle guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19620-01/805-3917/6j3niaoad/index.html), says this:

> #!/usr/dt/bin/dtksh tells the operating system that this script should be executed using /usr/dt/bin/dtksh rather than the standard shell.

And well, I have no idea how to proceed with this.

Thanks for came, please feel you free to comment any advice or question.

Comment: have you tried `whereis dtksh` or `man dtksh` ?

Comment: No. with **man** It says `no manual entry for dtksh` and **whereis** `dtksh:` Still searching.

Comment: What Linux are you using?

Comment: @kusalananda, SparkyLinux

Comment: SparkyLinux is a derivative of Debian. For Debian, I can find no package that contains `dtksh`. It is possible that you would have to compile the `ksh93` shell for yourself from sources, while at the same time enabling building `dtksh`, if at all possible.

Comment: I got `ksh93` in my system, but I don't know if is useful.